# Button's nested style trigger not executed after click

Tags: wpf, animation, button, styles

I've tried to recreate a material design kind of button. One of the animations of this button is that upon mouse over is that the color of the button changes to a darker hue of the original color.

In order to realise this for every color, I overlay my button with a rectangle and change it's opacity between 25 % and 0 % depending on mouse over or not. This style is implemented in the style of the rectangle. But it appears that this style is only executed before I click. Once I click the button, this style trigger is not executed anymore.

I've also implemented a animation to change the opacity of the rectangle to 40 % when the button is clicked. this animation however, is still visible after the first click.

I thought that it might be because the rectangle's style is included in the control template. But I don't know how to extract those styles from the control template to the button's style.

```
<Style x:Key="MaterialFlatButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                   <Grid>
                            <Rectangle RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Fill="#000000" Panel.ZIndex="1" x:Name="Reccie">
                                <Rectangle.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                                        <!--These styles-->
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter  Property="Opacity" Value="0.26"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                                                <Setter  Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.4" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25" />
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Rectangle.Style>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              Margin="16 0 16 0" TextBlock.FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoMedium}"
                                              TextBlock.FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeBody}" Typography.Capitals="AllSmallCaps"/>
                        </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <!--Should go here perhaps?-->
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.26"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: does it do what you want if you set FillBehavior="Stop"?

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.26" To="0.4" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Comment: I'm trying to keep all styling packed together in the style of the button, so that I do not need to copy certain things every time again when I make the button. So the first one doesn't really work for me. I did try to implement it in the <Style.trigger> section like that, but that didn't work.

The second part is a no-go anyhow. Changing the overal opacity, will cause the text-content of the button to also change it's opacity. I just want to make the background look darker. Also you cannot put the global opacity to 0 as you wouldn't see the button's text ...

Comment: Sorry, I had no access to it the last two days. This works like a charm! Thank you so much :) Where did you learn about this property?

Comment: "Remarks" section on this page describes your problem: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx